Is Openbrush still maintaining?
I noticed that the Openbrush smart contract hasn't been active for a year, and ink! is now at version 5, but OpenBrush hasn't provided support yet? Any ideas?
https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts

OpenBrush is no longer maintained. I would recommend using Pendzl -- a Web3 Foundation grantee project. They support ink! v5 as well. https://github.com/pendzl/Pendzl
